# Is being covered by another element Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element:

```html
<select aria-describedby="searchDropdownDescription" class="nav-search-dropdown searchSelect" data-nav-digest="Xa0GQ+pPQ/tdsV+GmRWeXB8PUD0=" data-nav-selected="0" id="searchDropdownBox" name="url" style="display: block;" tabindex="0" title="Search in">...</select>
```

is being covered by another element:

```html
<input type="text" id="twotabsearchtextbox" value="" name="field-keywords" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" class="nav-input" dir="auto" tabindex="0" aria-label="Search">
```

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
My code:

```js
describe('Amazon test', function()
{
    it('Matching book', function()
    {
        cy.visit("https://amazon.com")
        cy.title().should('eq',"Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more")
        cy.get('#twotabsearchtextbox').click({force: true}).get('#searchDropdownBox').select('Books')
        
    })
  })
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
cy.get('#twotabsearchtextbox')
  .click()
  .get('#searchDropdownBox')
  .select('Books', {force: true}) // <- add {force: true}
```

Comment: So the solution to solve the cypress problem is to move the force:true to the end?

Comment: What about if I do not want to user `{ force : true }` ?

Answer (score 10):

You want to click the `<select>` tag. But Cypress mocks a real person. A real person cannot click the `<select>` in a real browser, because `<select>` is covered by `<input>`.

So I think you may need to debug your page code firstly.

Reminder, the partial cover also will trigger this issue.